# Run a shell script from docker-compose command, inside the container

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I am attempting to run a shell script by using docker-compose inside the docker container. I am using the Dockerfile to build the container environment and installing all dependancies. I then copy all the project files to the container. This works well as far as I can determine. (I am still fairly new to docker, docker-compose)

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine3.7

RUN apk add --no-cache --update \
    python3 python3-dev gcc \
    gfortran musl-dev \
    libffi-dev openssl-dev

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV APP /app

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN mkdir $APP
WORKDIR $APP

ADD requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

What I am currently attempting is this:

docker-compose file:

```
version: "2"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./config/nginx/ssl/certs:/etc/ssl/certs
      - ./config/nginx/ssl/private:/etc/ssl/private
    depends_on:
      - api
  api:
    build: .
    container_name: app
    command: /bin/sh -c "entrypoint.sh"
    expose:
      - "5000"
```

This results in the container not starting up, and from the log I get the following:

```
/bin/sh: 1: entrypoint.sh: not found
```

For more reference and information this is my entrypoint.sh script:

```
python manage.py db init
python manage.py db migrate --message 'initial database migration'
python manage.py db upgrade
gunicorn -w 1 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 manage:app
```

Basically, I know I could run the container with only the gunicorn line above in the command line of the dockerfile. But, I am using a sqlite db inside the app container, and really need to run the db commands for the database to initialise/migrate.

Just for reference this is a basic Flask python web app with a nginx reverse proxy using gunicorn.

Any insight will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Give exact path to entrypoint.sh `command: /bin/sh -c "/path/to/entrypoint.sh"`

Comment: Thanks, managed to solve the issue, ended up having to ssh into the container to find that the entrypoint.sh script was never included in the container. The solution as per [Adiii] below proved useful in figuring that out.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First thing, You are copying `entrypoint.sh` to `$APP` which you passed from your build args but you did not mentioned that and second thing you need to set permission for `entrypoint.sh`. Better to add these three lines so you will not need to add `command` in docker-compose file.

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine3.7
RUN apk add --no-cache --update \
    python3 python3-dev gcc \
    gfortran musl-dev \
    libffi-dev openssl-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV APP /app
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN mkdir $APP
WORKDIR $APP
ADD requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
# These line for /entrypoint.sh
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT "/entrypoint.sh"
```

docker compose for api will be

```
  api:
    build: .
    container_name: app
    expose:
      - "5000"
```

or you can use you own also will work fine

```
version: "2"

services:
  api:
    build: .
    container_name: app
    command: /bin/sh -c "entrypoint.sh"
    expose:
      - "5000"
```

Now you can check with docker run command too.

```
docker run -it --rm myapp
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue for me. I ended up using only the first 2 lines added to the Dockerfile and running the /bin/sh -c "/entrypoint.sh" command from docker-compose. Basically to allow separation the container build vs running a container.

Comment: What does this line in Dockerfile do in your answer `entrypoint "/entrypoint.sh"`?

Comment: Got it, it's just `ENTRYPOINT "/entrypoint.sh"` without the capitalization

Answer (score 0):

`entrypoint.sh` needs to be specified with its full path.

It's not clear from your question where exactly you install it; if it's in the current directory, `./entrypoint.sh` should work.

In some more detail, the working directory *inside the container* is set by `WORKDIR`; and so, for example, if `WORKDIR` is `/foo` then `./entrypoint.sh` is equivalent to `/foo/entrypoint.sh`

(Tangentially, the `-c` option to `sh` is superfluous if you want to run a single script file.)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I wound up having to ssh into the container and discovering that the entrypoint.sh wasn't present, managed to solve it by including it in the Copy command via the Dockerfile.