# Uvicorn isn't running when I execute it via a script

Tags: python, bash, fastapi, uvicorn

If I run from the terminal `uvicorn main:app --reload` everything works.

When putting it in a `my_script.sh` file with:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec uvicorn main:app --reload
```

then nothing happens. Why?

I found this: [Uvicorn/FastAPI executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67453019/uvicorn-fastapi-executable), but it seems unanswered.

Comment: Why do you need the exeec ?

Answer (score 1):

You can instead add a `main` method (more specifically, [`if __name__ == "__main__":`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)) inside your existing Python script (i.e., `main.py` in your case) or a new Python script, where you `run` the uvicorn server, allowing you to set parameters, such as `host`, `port`, `reload`, `workers`, etc. (as shown [here](https://www.uvicorn.org/#running-programmatically)), and simply execute that Python script from inside your bash script. Have a look [here](https://www.uvicorn.org/#command-line-options) for all the available `options`.

```
import uvicorn

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True)
```

**Edit**: Since you mentioned [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71249447/uvicorn-isnt-running-when-i-execute-it-via-a-script#comment125951658_71250692) that you *"have the script defined in the entrypoint section of docker-compose"*, make sure you give the exact path to the bash script, as well as it has permissions to execute. Have a look at the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57840820/run-a-shell-script-from-docker-compose-command-inside-the-container) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882654/docker-entrypoint-running-bash-script-gets-permission-denied). I would also suggest to take a look at the [relevant FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/docker/).

Comment: Hi there,

i tried this as well with no result :(

I have the script defined in the entrypoint section of docker-compose. When i start it it just exits with errcode 0.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the `exes` from bash script. might be it is a cause of your failure.